# webpack -p results in: Unexpected token name «i», expected punc «;»

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

Happened all of a sudden, to my knowledge nothing out of the ordinary has been changed - maybe I added a third party library with NPM, but nothing more really.

```
ERROR in /static/js/vendor.bundle.ed01c274b6d1500252a2.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token name «i», expected punc «;» [/static/js/vendor.bundle.ed01c274b6d1500252a2.js:59428,13]
```

Sometimes, it will trigger in my own `bundle.js` as well, it seems inconsistent.

The **package.json** command are:

```
"dev": "export NODE_ENV=dev && webpack --progress --colors --watch",
"build": "export NODE_ENV=prod && webpack -p",
```

**npm run dev** works just fine. **npm run build** does not and produces the above error.

Comment: Most likely not a Webpack error but an error in one of your dependencies (notice vendor.bundle)

Comment: I would imagine so too; but if I remove my recently added dependencies, it will throw the same error in my own bundle.js.

Comment: You were correct, it was the module `isemail` that I used to validate email inputs. It apparently doesn't like being minified.